# possible loss of precision error in java

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
class test{

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        int a=10, b=20;
        float c = 30.123;
        int e = (int)c;
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
test.java:6: error: possible loss of precision
        float c = 30.123;
                  ^
required: float
found:    double
1 error
```

Why all these?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Floating point literals are by default of `double` type. And assigning a double value to a float type will result in some precision error. You can either change the `type` of `c` to `double`, or append an `f` at the end of it to make it `float` like so:

```
float c = 30.123f;
```

Comment: @Eng.Fouad. :) Just trying to keep my mind busy, so that it doesn't get rusted. ;)

Comment: The reason for double as default literal type is that double is very much the normal floating point type in Java. I would only use float if I were dealing with a very large set of numbers with limited precision and well behaved processing. Changing the type of c to double would be a better fix.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify float value without f at the end it is treated as `double` which is by-default.

```
double d = 30.123;
```

For float literal you should append f at the end of float value.

```
float c = 30.123f;
```