# Possible loss of precision error vs. Type mismatch error

Tags: java, java-7

So everyone is posting that when they write the following code, they get the "Possible loss of precision" error:

```
float c= 30.123;
```

I tried the same code and compilation failed with this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float". I'm running this with Java 7.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`30.123` is implicitly a `double`.  The compiler is telling you that you lose precision when you assign a `double` value to a `float` variable.  Make it

```
float c = 30.123f;
```

[Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

---

The different error messages are coming from different IDEs.  I put that line in a file and checked it in three IDEs and tried to compile it from the command prompt and I got four different error messages.

Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\Bill\Desktop>javac Num.java  
Num.java:5: error: possible loss of precision  
       float c= 30.123;  
                ^  
  required: float  
  found:    double  
1 error
```

IntelliJ:

> Incompatible types.
>   Required: float
>   Found: double

Eclipse:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float

BlueJ:

> possible loss of precision
>   required: float; found: double

Comment: But I did not have a "loss precision" error; I got a different error. In this question(#14839320) the guy had the "loss precision" error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839320/possible-loss-of-precision-error-in-java

So my question is that why I have a different error? did Java 7 changed the way it compiles this code from Java 6?

Comment: @RandaSbeity That's just different IDEs giving different error messages.  See the edit to my answer.

Comment: That makes sense. I was using eclipse. Thank you so much :)